# How to remove the header/footer from the printing page?

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to remove default header/footer on printing page in landscape mode.

This is woking fine for landscape mode :

```
@page{
    size: landscape; //Showing header footer with landscape layout
}
```

Change page layout:

```
@page{
    size: landscape;
    margin: 0mm; //removed header footer but change page layout 
}
```

Comment: Consider using media print to define print specific rules. You probably just want something like .class, #ID { display: none; }

Answer (score 0):

@page{size: landscape;} is not fully supported by browsers and is listed for the deprecation.

There is an hack to get the desired behavior, use

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

to rotate your page for print.